# primefaces dataTable rowEditor custom validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable and when i edit it i want it to validate if assignedQuota >= usedQuota. How can i do that?

```
<p:dataTable id="vessels" var="ves" value="#{assignedVessels}" editable="true">
  <p:column>
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">
               <p:outputLabel value="#{ves.assignedQuota}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
               <p:inputText value="#{ves.assignedQuota}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>    
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
               <p:outputLabel value="#{ves.usedQuota}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
               <p:inputText value="#{ves.usedQuota}" />
             </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>
   <p:column>
      <p:rowEditor/> 
   </p:column>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***ajax event***, for example put:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bean.onRowEdit}"/>
```

Into ***p:dataTable*** and in bean create follow method:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    // add you check here (assignedQuota >= usedQuota)
}
```

see also [datatable edit example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution you could just check this condition in your controller.
A more elegant way would be a custom constraint validator for your vessel bean. See [hibernat doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html) for example.

The only trick here is that you have to create a validator for the bean (`@Target({TYPE})`), not for a single quota-value. Validators on members can't reference other members.